# Flutter Navigate back to home Screen after a time when there is no interaction on the second Screen

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter beginner needs help.
Is it possible that the app by himself without a press of a button, navigates from a second screen to the home screen after a period of time, if there is no any interaction on the second Screen.
For example in the following code is it possible to make this?
I don't know how to implement this.
Thanks in advance for some help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Navigate to a new screen on Button click'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Colors.teal,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Screen2()));
          },
          child: Text('GO TO SCREEN 2'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Navigate to a new screen on Button click'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          textColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home()));

          },
          child: Text('GO TO HOME'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would recommend pop and not push because Flutter navigator works like a stack.

Next, you can set a timer in the initState function:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

for a better solution, I would set a timer in the initState function and wrap the entire page with GestureDetector, so that each gesture resets the timer.

Use GestureDetector's behavior property and pass HitTestBehavior.opaque to it, which recognizes entire screen and detects the tap when you tap anywhere on the screen. like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  Timer? searchOnStoppedTyping;
  _onChangeHandler() {
    const duration = Duration(milliseconds: 800); // set the duration that you want call pop() after that.
    if (searchOnStoppedTyping != null) {
      searchOnStoppedTyping?.cancel(); // clear timer
    }
   searchOnStoppedTyping = new Timer(duration, () => navigateHome());
  }

  navigateHome() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _onChangeHandler();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Navigate to a new screen on Button click'), backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
      body: GestureDetector(
        //Use GestureDetector's behavior property and pass HitTestBehavior.opaque to it, which recognizes entire screen and detects the tap when you tap anywhere on the screen.
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onTap: _onChangeHandler,
          child: yourBody...,
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi David... Thanks a lot for your help.It is exactly what i needed. One more think. The GestureDetector works fine on a Android App. What i realized is that if the App is for Windows Desktop it does not work. It does not detect the mouse. Is there any way to make it also work in a Desktop app?

Comment: I found this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html.. Now it is also working with the mouse on Desktop. Thanks for the help again

Comment: wow really nice and well answered in deep details!

Comment: glad I could help @CarlosCosta

Answer (score 2):

```
    class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
    }
    
    class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
// try to add init state and add timer inside it then it will navigate after duration
     void initState() {
         super.initState();
         Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), (){
           Navigator.of(context).pop(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home()));
         });


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Navigate to a new screen on Button click'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent),
          body: Center(
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
            // i moved this line inside the Timer , look at initState
              },
              child: Text('GO TO HOME'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmed for the help. This helped me out